# use varchar value as column name to select a value

Tags: mysql, stored-functions

i am writing a mysql function to delete a row and have a backup in a key value pair table . I am able to do most but fail in selecting a value from a retrieved column name

```
     CREATE FUNCTION delete_item (
  item_id_val int,
  cur_usr_id int,
  item_type_val varchar(45),
  current_purpose varchar(45),
  cur_date datetime
) RETURNS INT
BEGIN
  declare col_name varchar(45);
  declare no_of_cols int;
  declare ind int;
  declare c1 cursor for select column_name from information_schema.columns where table_name='tbl_name';
  select count(column_name) from information_schema.columns where table_name='tbl_name' into no_of_cols;
  open c1;
  while no_of_cols > 0 do
    fetch c1 into col_name;
    insert into deleted_data(tbl_name,field_nm,val,activity_date) values('tbl_name',col_name,
    (**select col_name from tbl_name where item_id=item_id_val**),cur_date);
    set no_of_cols = no_of_cols-1;
  end while;
  close c1;
  return 1;
```

the bold text(*ed text) saves the column name itself in the place of value . i need to store the value of that column name in that table . need help guys

Comment: atleast i need a provision like select index from tbl_name where item_id=item_id_val . index++ . like 'select 1 from tbl_name'

Comment: i did it by making it as a procedure and making the problematic statement as a dynamic sql statement
i also used a table'temp_deleted_cols' for temporary usage to store req data . i couldnt post the answer
also thanks for this link [Roland Bouman's blog][1]


  [1]: http://rpbouman.blogspot.com/2005/11/mysql-5-prepared-statement-syntax-and.html